# How to make navbar menu elements only visible for mobile?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

My navbar looks like this on desktop:

[image: Navbar]

It works fine on mobile.

I would like to display the items one by one on desktop, and make the menu icon vanish.

My code:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-inverse">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <img src="vc-transp.png" href="#" height="50px">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" style="background-color: transparent; border-color: transparent; filter: invert(100%); padding-top: 8px;"type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><b>Dashboard</b></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Protect</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </nav>
```

```css
.nav a{
  color: white !important;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.navbar-brand{
  color: white !important;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
a:link {
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #D4E1E4;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #D4E1E4;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please clarify the question. What do you mean one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the default `navbar` template for that.

After `992px`, your hamburger menu icon will vanish and menu items are shown in a horizontal manner.

before `992px`, your hamburger menu will show and menu items are shown in a vertical manner with a collapsing feature.

You can manage `px` with `navbar-expand-*` class, I used `navbar-expand-lg`class here, where lg stands for `992px`

```css
.nav a {
  color: white !important;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  color: white !important;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

a:link {
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #D4E1E4;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #D4E1E4;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="vc-transp.png" height="50px"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><b>Dashboard</b></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Protect</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```